# Select the field that ever fulfil condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Employee Table

```
 NameId  Name
 1       Andy
 2       Peter
 3       Jason
 4       Thomas
 5       Clark
```

Employee - Supervisor Relations

```
NameId  SupervisorId (Refer to employee Id)
1       4
1       2
2       3
5       4
```

How can i select query to return search with all name that supervisor 'once' to be Thomas. So the result i want is like this.

```
Name  Supervisor
Andy  Thomas       
Andy  Peter (Is valid because Andy supervisor contains 'Thomas')
Clark Thomas
```

Comment: Clearly `Name` is not unique.

Comment: It just example, actually real condition still id

Comment: @WawoBrown . . . No, you should construct a question that makes sense.

Comment: Okay i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the table relation doesn't need another optional table, so the query would be more simple:

```
select emp.name as Name, spv.name as Supervisor
from employee emp
inner join employee spv
   on emp.spv_id = spv.id
where spv.name like 'Thomas'
order by emp.name
```